# Fixing body to scroll within a section doesn't work smooth

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scrollbar

I am trying to make an animation for the website I do, the general idea of it is:

1. User scrolls down the page and sees block with cards that are not displayed fully
2. When he scrolls so these cards are reaching the top of the viewport, the body should fix itself and cards should scroll within 100vh container.

I managed to come to a really close success with it, but there is a problem - if I am not using a touchpad, but am using a mouse it seems like I need to do one more mouse scroll to start cards scrolling within container.

Cannot get what's wrong with it or is my approach just wrong in general.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

There is my [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7xhs1z5/1/) for more details.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var page = $("body");
    var container = $("#container");
    var containerTop = container.offset().top;



    var lastWindowTop = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        console.log("Scrolling down window: ", isScrollingDown(lastWindowTop, windowTop));

        if (isScrollingDown(lastWindowTop, windowTop) && windowTop > containerTop && !isScrolledTillTheEnd(container)) {
            container.addClass("allow-scroll");
            page.addClass("stop-scroll");
        }

        if (!isScrollingDown(lastWindowTop, windowTop) && containerTop > windowTop && isScrolledTillTheEnd(container)) {
            container.addClass("allow-scroll");
            page.addClass("stop-scroll");
        }



        lastWindowTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    });

    var lastContainerTop = 0;
    container.scroll(function () {
        var containerTop = container.scrollTop();
        // console.log("Scrolling down: ", isScrollingDown(lastContainerTop, containerTop));

        if(isScrollingDown(lastContainerTop, containerTop) && isScrolledTillTheEnd(container)){
            container.removeClass("allow-scroll");
            page.removeClass("stop-scroll");
        }

        if(!isScrollingDown(lastContainerTop, containerTop) && isScrolledTillTheTop(container)){
            container.removeClass("allow-scroll");
            page.removeClass("stop-scroll");
        }


        lastContainerTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    });


    function isScrolledTillTheEnd(e){

        return (e[0].scrollHeight - e[0].offsetHeight) <= e.scrollTop();
    }

    function isScrolledTillTheTop(element){
        return element.scrollTop() == 0;
    }

    function isScrollingDown(lastWindowTop, currentWindowScrollTop) {
        return currentWindowScrollTop > lastWindowTop;
    }

});
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.card-container{
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100vh;
    border-radius: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.allow-scroll{
    overflow: auto;
}

.stop-scroll{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card{
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
        <div style="background-color: red; height: 300px;"></div>
        <div style="background-color: green; height: 400px;"></div>
        
        <div id="container" class="card-container" style="background-color: yellow;">
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
        </div>

        <div style="background-color: purple; height: 500px;"></div>
        <div style="background-color: navy; height: 500px;"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I cannot see the problem - I'm using Window10/Edge. As soon as the cards hit the top of the viewport that 'inner' scrollbar appears, positioned at the top which I assume is what is required. What should I be seeing and what OS/browser are you using?

Comment: I am using MacOS and was seeing this issue on Chrome/Safari.
I know that my friends tested it on Windows and had it too.

Try scrolling up and down quickly and using your mouse wheel.